# How to submit information using Django?

Tags: javascript, django

I have the following form in a modal and I want to save the information in the DB but it does not happen. But if I manage to remove an attribute from the submit button if I save it but the button validations and actions disappear.

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-kt-account-modal-action="submit">
```

replacing with this if it works and saves but validations no longer work.

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

This is JS

```
    const i = t.querySelector('[data-kt-account-modal-action="submit"]');
                i.addEventListener("click", (t => {
                    t.preventDefault(), o && o.validate().then((function(t) {
                        console.log("validated!"), "Valid" == t ? (i.setAttribute("data-kt-indicator", "on"), i.disabled = !0, setTimeout((function() {
                            i.removeAttribute("data-kt-indicator"), i.disabled = !1, Swal.fire({
                                text: "Form has been successfully submitted!",
                                icon: "success",
                                buttonsStyling: !1,
                                confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                                customClass: {
                                    confirmButton: "btn btn-primary"
                                }
                            }).then((function(t) {
                                t.isConfirmed && n.hide()
                            }))
                        }), 2e3)) : Swal.fire({
                            text: "Sorry, looks like there are some errors detected, please try again.",
                            icon: "error",
                            buttonsStyling: !1,
                            confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                            customClass: {
                                confirmButton: "btn btn-primary"
                            }
                        })
                    }))
                })),
```

Help Me I can't get the form to be saved in my DB I have already tried everything if someone helps me I will appreciate it very much.

Thi is HTML Affceted

```
<div class="text-center pt-15">
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-white me-3" data-kt-account-modal-action="cancel">Discard</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-kt-account-modal-action="submit">
        <span class="indicator-label">Submit</span>
        <span class="indicator-progress">Please wait... 
        <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-middle ms-2"></span></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

This is a little more of the extract where I get an error when trying to save the form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but if you're using Django, I assume it will.
*Note - I am using getbootstrap, so try 'importing' that package onto the HTML if it doesn't work first time*

Say we have a function in views.py, something like this:

```
def webPage(request):
    var = request.POST.get("number")
    return render(request, 'webPage.html', ANY_OTHER_VARIABLES)
```

Now on the HTML, for a text box...,

```
<form  action="" method="POST" >
                
                <label for="number">Your variable: </label>
                <input id="number" type="number" name="number">
                <input type="submit" value="Check">
            </form>
```

And for the button, you can do something like:

```
<form  action="" method="POST" >
                <input type="submit" value="Check">
                <input type = "hidden" name = "returnVariable" value = 'PUT_YOUR_VALUE_HERE">
            </form>
```

While this did work for me, it may not work for you. If you have any questions, feel free to ask, but I think a bit of Googling should help.